# How to fix 'The input was not found in the haystack' in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-select

I have an issue in my code which I can't resolve. I'm using Zend framework 2.4 and I wrote a form but as soon as I validate it, I got the error ***The input was not found in the haystack***. This are the 3 input where I got the error:

```
 $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'ACTIVITE1',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'required' => 'required',
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'Choisir l\'activité'
            ),
            'disable_inarray_validator' => false,
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'select-session1'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'ACTIVITE2',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'required' => 'required',
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'Choisir l\'activité'
            )
        ),
        'disable_inarray_validator' => false,
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'select-session2'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'ACTIVITE3',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'required' => 'required',
        'options' => array(
            'value_options' => array(
                'Choisir l\'activité'
            )
        ),
        'disable_inarray_validator' => false,
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id' => 'select-session3'
        )
    ));
```

I saw in other form that I should put `'disable_inarray_validator' => false` but this doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's not working.

That message comes from the `\Zend\Validator\InArray` and essentially, it means: "*your user is doing something hacky with your select, pay attention*".

An exemple would be a Select `Preferred fruit` with two options, like "Banana" and "Ananas", but the user "hacks" the select and sends to the server the value "Audi". The `InArray` validator is really important and shouldn't be disabled (well, only in a few exceptions..).

Now, why are you getting this error? The answer is... You didn't told what are the select options. You created a Select, but you didn't specified what are its options. You put the label/placeholder at the place of the options. A correct Select would be:

```php
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'ACTIVITE1',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'required' => 'required',
    'options' => array(
        'value_options' => array(
            1 => 'Fitness',
            2 => 'Parcour',
            3 => 'Velo',
            4 => 'Tapis roulant',
            // ... and so on
        )
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'id' => 'select-session1',
        'placeholder' => "Choisir l'activité"
    )
));
```

What is "weird" is the fact that you are filling something in an empty select, and my question then is: **why?**

Selects are (typically) there for a predefined list of values. If you want to allow your users to fill a custom text, then you should consider to create a `Text` field with the autocomplete option.

### Edit: select with values from DB

If you want to create a select with a list of options that come from the database, the route is a bit more complex, but once you've learned how to do it, it will become way easier.

**PAY ATTENTION**: this will not be a "copy&paste solution". Since I'm not having access to your code, I'm making up names (classes, namespaces, methods, variables) just to create a complete example :)

First off, you must create a custom element. In this case, it will be a custom select:

```php
namespace Yournamespace;

use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Yournamespace\ActivityMapper;

class ActivitySelect extends Select {

    protected $activityMapper;

    public function __construct(ActivityMapper $activityMapper, $name = null, $options = []) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
        $this->activityMapper = $activityMapper;
    }

    public function init() {
        $valueOptions = [];
        foreach ($this->activityMapper->fetchAll() as $activity) {
            $valueOptions[$activity->getActivityId()] = $activity->getActivityName();
        }
        $this->setValueOptions($valueOptions);
    }

}
```

What is **really important** here is that you must instantiate your element (options, classes, and so on..) inside `init` method.

Since this element has a dependency (`ActivityMapper`), you'll have to create a factory for this element:

```php
namespace Yournamespace;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class ActivitySelectFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null): object {
        $activityMapper = $container->get(\Yournamespace\ActivityMapper::class);
        return \Yournamespace\ActivitySelect($activityMapper);
    }

}
```

This factory must be added in the configuration, more precisely, inside `module.config.php`:

```php
return [
    // ...
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            \Yournamespace\ActivitySelect::class => \Yournamespace\ActivitySelectFactory::class,
        ]
    ]
    // ...
];
```

Now, you must modify your form too. All elements must be added to form inside `init` method, and not inside the constructor:

```php
namespace Yournamespace;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class ActivityForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        // ...
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'ACTIVITE1',
            'type' => \Yournamespace\ActivitySelect::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'select-session1',
                'required' => true, // This will work only clientside, don't forget the inputfilter!
                'placeholder' => 'Choisir l\'activité',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Choisir l\'activité',
            ]
        ]);
        // ...

    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        // ...
        $inputFilter[] = [
            'name' => 'ACTIVITE1',
            'required' => true
        ];
        // ...
        return $inputFilter;
    }

}
```

Finally, you'll have to modify your controller too, because you need to retrieve the form from the `FormElementManager`:

```php
namespace Yournamespace;

use Zend\Form\FormElementManager;

class YourController extends AbstractActionController {
    private $formManager;

    public function __construct(FormElementManager $formManager) {
        $this->formManager = $formManager;
    }

    public function choisirActiviteAction(){
        // ...
        $form = $this->formManager->get(\Yournamespace\ActivityForm::class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

A next nice step would be to create a controller plugin for the `$formManager`, instead of making it as a dependency of each controller, but this is a different problem..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer! I understand what you mean but i did this because i don't want to control the select because i can't control all the possible options.

Because the options are from a database, i get them doing an AJAX request and i add all the option to the select in the view. So the options can vary and are not fixed.

Here is my AJAX request :

```
$("#input-dtNaissance").change(function() {
        $.when($(".activites-options").remove()).then(function() {
            if ($("#input-dtNaissance").val() != " ") {
                //on supprime les anciennes activités proposées au cas où il y en ai
                var year = $("#input-dtNaissance").val().substring(0,4);
                if (year == "") {
                    year = 1;
                }
                // si date supprimée/réinitialisée 
                if (year == 1) {
                    // on supprime les activités proposées du select
                    $(".activites-options").remove();
                } else {
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost/ecoleMunicipalSport/app/public/activite/listActivitySession1/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(element => {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "' class='activites-options'>" + element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session1").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost/ecoleMunicipalSport/app/public/activite/listActivitySession2/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(element => {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "'class='activites-options'>" + element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session2").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost/ecoleMunicipalSport/app/public/activite/listActivitySession3/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(element => {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "' class='activites-options'>" + element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session3").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

I know that it's not very safety and if you have a better solution with more security i'm open to the propositions.

Good evening.

PS : Sorree faur my terribl anglish :)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't controll al the possible options"? If you have a predefined list of options that can't be extended, then use a select and fill it with that list, otherwise use a text field.
If you have all your options in the database, create a custom select. I'll post an exemple later..

Comment: all my options are in my database and i'm beginner in ZF2 so i'm going to check how to create a custom select and see if that can work with my project

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325100/zend-framework-3-custom-elements), I'll post a detailed solution in a couple hours ;)

Comment: Take a look at the [update answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59034763/1842846)