# Keep old value of a select field in a form - Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on an application with ZF 2.8 and i'm trying to maintains the value of a form in case of user input error.

The old datas of the other fields (type `<input>`) are "still there" if there is a user input error but for the `<select>` that is not working and i can't understand why...?!

Here is the code of the controller :

```php
public function addAction() {
        $form = new InscriptionForm();  
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $inscription = new Inscription();
            $form->setInputFilter($inscription->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid() && ($request->getPost('ACTIVITE1') != 0 || $request->getPost('ACTIVITE2') != 0 || $request->getPost('ACTIVITE3') != 0)) {
                $data = $form->getData();
                $inscription->exchangeArray($data);
                $lastId = $this->getInscriptionTable()->saveInscription($inscription);
                $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
// code - requests
 } else {
                $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
                $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $statement = $adapter->query(
                    "
                    SELECT *
                    FROM session
                    "
                );
                $results = $statement->execute();
                if ($request->getPost('ACTIVITE1') == 0 && $request->getPost('ACTIVITE2') == 0 && $request->getPost('ACTIVITE3') == 0) {
                    return new ViewModel(array(
                        'errors' => 'Le formulaire contient une ou plusieurs erreurs : Au moins une activité doit être renseignée.',
                        'form' => $form,
                        'sessions' => $results
                    ));
                } else {
                    return new ViewModel(array(
                        'errors' => 'Le formulaire contient une ou plusieurs erreurs.',
                        'form' => $form,
                        'sessions' => $results
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $statement = $adapter->query(
            "
            SELECT *
            FROM session
            "
        );
        $results = $statement->execute();
            
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
            'sessions' => $results
        ));
    }
```

The model Inscription :

```php
<?php

namespace Inscription\Model;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\NotEmpty;
use Zend\Validator\Date;
use Zend\Validator\Regex;

class Inscription implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

    public $id_inscription;
    public $dt_inscription;
    // i delete some attributes because the post was too long
    // from insc_sess
    public $activite1;
    public $activite2;
    public $activite3;

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    public function exchangeArray($data) {
        $this->id_inscription     = (!empty($data['ID_INSCRIPTION'])) ? $data['ID_INSCRIPTION'] : null;
        $this->dt_inscription = (!empty($data['DT_INSCRIPTION'])) ? $data['DT_INSCRIPTION'] : null;

        $this->nom_enfant  = (!empty($data['NOM_ENFANT'])) ? $data['NOM_ENFANT'] : null;
        $this->prenom_enfant     = (!empty($data['PRENOM_ENFANT'])) ? $data['PRENOM_ENFANT'] : null;
        $this->sexe_enfant = (!empty($data['SEXE_ENFANT'])) ? $data['SEXE_ENFANT'] : null;
        $this->dtNaissance_enfant  = (!empty($data['DTNAISSANCE_ENFANT'])) ? $data['DTNAISSANCE_ENFANT'] : null;
        $this->nom_ecole    = (!empty($data['NOM_ECOLE'])) ? $data['NOM_ECOLE'] : null;

        $this->resp1 = (!empty($data['RESP1'])) ? $data['RESP1'] : null;
        $this->adresse_resp1  = (!empty($data['ADRESSE_RESP1'])) ? $data['ADRESSE_RESP1'] : null;
        $this->tel_Resp1     = (!empty($data['TEL_RESP1'])) ? $data['TEL_RESP1'] : null;
        $this->mail_Resp1 = (!empty($data['MAIL_RESP1'])) ? $data['MAIL_RESP1'] : null;

        $this->resp2  = (!empty($data['RESP2'])) ? $data['RESP2'] : null;
        $this->adresse_resp2  = (!empty($data['ADRESSE_RESP2'])) ? $data['ADRESSE_RESP2'] : null;
        $this->tel_Resp2  = (!empty($data['TEL_RESP2'])) ? $data['TEL_RESP2'] : null;
        $this->mail_Resp2 = (!empty($data['MAIL_RESP2'])) ? $data['MAIL_RESP2'] : null;

        $this->activite1 = (!empty($data['ACTIVITE1'])) ? $data['ACTIVITE1'] : null;
        $this->activite2 = (!empty($data['ACTIVITE2'])) ? $data['ACTIVITE2'] : null;
        $this->activite3 = (!empty($data['ACTIVITE3'])) ? $data['ACTIVITE3'] : null;

        $this->autorise1  = (!empty($data['AUTORISE1'])) ? $data['AUTORISE1'] : null;
        $this->autorise2     = (!empty($data['AUTORISE2'])) ? $data['AUTORISE2'] : null;
        $this->saitNager = (!empty($data['SAITNAGER'])) ? $data['SAITNAGER'] : null;
        $this->traitement  = (!empty($data['TRAITEMENT'])) ? $data['TRAITEMENT'] : null;
        $this->ouiTraitement     = (!empty($data['OUITRAITEMENT'])) ? $data['OUITRAITEMENT'] : null;
        $this->allergies = (!empty($data['ALLERGIES'])) ? $data['ALLERGIES'] : null;
        $this->autresAllergies  = (!empty($data['AUTRESALLERGIES'])) ? $data['AUTRESALLERGIES'] : null;
        $this->autreSante     = (!empty($data['AUTRESSANTE'])) ? $data['AUTRESSANTE'] : null;

        $this->coche = (!empty($data['COCHE'])) ? $data['COCHE'] : null;
        $this->dateNew  = (!empty($data['DTNEW'])) ? $data['DTNEW'] : null;
        $this->utilNew     = (!empty($data['UTILNEW'])) ? $data['UTILNEW'] : null;
        $this->dateMAJ = (!empty($data['DTMAJ'])) ? $data['DTMAJ'] : null;
        $this->utilMAJ  = (!empty($data['UTILMAJ'])) ? $data['UTILMAJ'] : null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'DTNAISSANCE_ENFANT',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Champ obligatoire"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'SAITNAGER',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Champ obligatoire"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'TRAITEMENT',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Champ obligatoire"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $inputFilter->add(array(
                'name'     => 'COCHE',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => "Champ obligatoire"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                ),
            ));
            
            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }
        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

The InscriptionForm class :

```php
<?php

namespace Inscription\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Element\Date;

class InscriptionForm extends Form {

    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct('inscription');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ID_INSCRIPTION',
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'required' => 'required'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'NOM_ENFANT',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => ' * Nom :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'PRENOM_ENFANT',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Prénom :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'SEXE_ENFANT',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Sexe :',
                'value_options' => array(
                    'F' => 'Fille',
                    'G' => 'Garçon',
                ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
               
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'DTNAISSANCE_ENFANT',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Date de naissance :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control date-field',
                'id' => 'input-dtNaissance',
                'placeholder' => 'jj/mm/AAAA',
                'pattern' => '^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'NOM_ECOLE',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Nom de l\'école :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ACTIVITE1',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => array(
                    'Choisir l\'activité'
                ),
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'select-session1'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ACTIVITE2',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => array(
                    'Choisir l\'activité'
                ),
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'select-session2'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ACTIVITE3',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => array(
                    'Choisir l\'activité'
                ),
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'id' => 'select-session3'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'RESP1',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Nom, prénom Responsable 1:',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ADRESSE_RESP1',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Adresse Responsable 1:',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'TEL_RESP1',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Téléphone Responsable 1:',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
            'pattern' => '^0[1-78]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                 'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'MAIL_RESP1',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Mail Responsable 1:',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'RESP2',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Nom, Prénom Responsable 2 :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ADRESSE_RESP2',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Adresse Responsable 2 :',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        )); 

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'TEL_RESP2',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Téléphone Responsable 2 :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'pattern' => '^0[1-78]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        )); 

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'MAIL_RESP2',
            //'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Mail Responsable 2 :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'AUTORISE1',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Nom, prénom :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                    'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'AUTORISE2',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'required' => 'required',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Nom, prénom :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                    'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'SAITNAGER',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Sait Nager :',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 'O',
                'unchecked_value' => 'N'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'input-SaitNager'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'TRAITEMENT',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Traitement :',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 'O',
                'unchecked_value' => 'N'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'input-Traitement'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'OUITRAITEMENT',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Si oui lequel :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                    'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ALLERGIES',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
            'options' => array(
                'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
                'label' => '* Allergies : ',
                'value_options' => array(
                    'Aucune' => 'Aucune',
                    'Asthmatiques' => 'Asthmatiques',
                    'Médicamenteuses' => 'Médicamenteuses',
                    'Alimentaires' => 'Alimentaires',
                    'Autres' => 'Autres',
                ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'input-allegies'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'AUTRESALLERGIES',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Si autres, précisez :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'input-autresallergies',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                    'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'AUTRESSANTE',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Autres difficultés de santé :',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'input-autresante',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'rows' => "5",
                    'style' => 'text-transform : uppercase'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'COCHE',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => '* Je certifie que ces informations sont correctes :',
                'use_hidden_element' => true,
                'checked_value' => 'O',
                'unchecked_value' => ''
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'checkbox-coche'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'submit',
            'options' => array(
                'value' => 'Valider',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'validation-form-inscription',
                'class' => 'button-default'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

The selects concerned by my problem are named `ACTIVITE1`/`ACTIVITE2`/`ACTIVITE3`...
Options of these select is load with json, the idea is to propose activity depending on the birth date informed in the form.

Here is the jQuery code to load the option of the select :

```js
        $().ready(function() {
            var dateNaissance = $("#input-dtNaissance").val();
            if (dateNaissance != "") {
                var year = $("#input-dtNaissance").val().substring(6,10);
                if (year == "") {
                    year = 1;
                }
                // si date supprimée/réinitialisée 
                if (year == 1) {
                // on supprime les activités proposées du select
                $(".activites-options").remove();
                } else {
                    $.getJSON("<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/activite/listActivitySession1/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(function(element) {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "' class='activites-options'>" +element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session1").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                    $.getJSON("<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/activite/listActivitySession2/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(function(element) {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "'class='activites-options'>" + element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session2").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                    $.getJSON("<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/activite/listActivitySession3/" + year, function(data) {
                        data.forEach(function(element) {
                            var option = "<option value='" + element.ID_ACTIVITES + "' class='activites-options'>" + element.activite[0] + element.activite.substring(1).toLowerCase() + " avec " + element.INTERVENANT + " - " + element.HORAIREDEB + "/" + element.HORAIREFIN + " (" + element.site[0] + element.site.substring(1).toLowerCase() + ")" + "</option>";
                            $("#select-session3").append(option);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

If someone got in idea, i'll appreciate it because i'm a bit stuck right now! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you publish the "Inscription" class?

Comment: yep, i have edited my post :)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is validation. What are the options for those three selects? Aren't you passing a value that isn't accepted by select validators?

Comment: The options of the select come from the database, i serialize them into json and i load them in the view.

Comment: What's the name of the select field? When you call setData, options data is already injected?

Comment: @skywalskurt what do you mean "you load them in the view"? You set the option **ONLY** in the view, or you create the form elements with those values? Can you also add `InscriptionForm` class code?

Comment: i have edited my post with the missing class, i load them only in the view but i create the select element also in the InscriptionForm class

Comment: @SergioRinaudo yes, options are injected before the form submissions and the setData function is called when the form is submit. The name of the select are "ACTIVITE1"/"ACTIVITE2"/"ACTIVITE3"

Comment: So you render your select options using only frontend code. This means that your backend is totally unaware about the values ( all selects are empty ) so it is not possible to make "selected" a value that is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, the problem is that your select elements don't have any options.

This means that, at validation time, the form tries to bind and validate a value that isn't in the options *he knows*.

In practice, the situation is the following:

- you create a `Select` element with no option
- you add this select to the form
- you create the form in the controller and pass it to the view
- in the view, you **PRINT** the following options (value, label):

  - 1, Football
  - 2, Cyclisme
  - 3, Basket
  - 4, Pétanque

These values exist only in the view. For the form, all these values don't exists. This means that:

- you click the "submit button", sending the POST request
- you set the data to the form
- form will try to bind value "4" to element `activite1`
- form will fail to bind this value, because it isn't a valid option in your select (since you created it empty)
- `activity1` will then result as empty, and it will be passed to the view

This is why the values of these select areflushed when there is an error in the form.

To fix this problem, you'll have to (best solution):

- create a custom element class, like `ActivitySelect`, where you'll create a select with all these options
- instead of using `Select` type in your form, you'll use `ActivitySelect`
- you'll create all needed factories required
- you'll retrieve the form via the FormElementManager.

A similar, simplier and a bit worse solution, would be to create a factory to the form, where you'll pass all necessary objects to create the options to your form. This will avoid to create a custom element class, but I find this solution not so clean for maintainability

Since this question has been answered a few time, I'll avoid to re-write everything in here and link one:

- [How to fix 'The input was not found in the haystack' in ZF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991185/how-to-fix-the-input-was-not-found-in-the-haystack-in-zf2/59034763#59034763)
- [Form custom elements with factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325100/form-custom-elements-with-factories)