# Additional attributes in select options

Tags: php, forms, select, laminas

In createForm.php I have code:

```
$this->add([
        'type' => Element\Select::class,
        'name' => 'subcategory_id',
        'options' =>[
                'label' => 'Subcategory',
                'empty_option' => 'Select...',
                'value_options' => $subcategoriesTable->fetchAllSubcategories(),
        ],
        'attributes' => [
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'custom-select',
        ],
]);
```

In SubcategoriesTable.php

```
public function fetchAllSubcategories()
{
        $sqlQuery = $this->sql->select()->order('sub_name ASC');
        $sqlStmt = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($sqlQuery);
        $handler = $sqlStmt->execute();

        $row = [];

        foreach($handler as $tuple){
                $row[$tuple['subcategory_id']] = $tuple['sub_name'];
        }
        return $row;
}
```

And generated records from my database to my form:

```html
<option value="1">Name1</option>
```

How I can change my code for making additional attribute like this?

```html
<option value="1" data-chained="parent_name">Name1</option>
```

parent name value is from another select. Also generated in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make a few changes.

Inside `SubcategoriesTable`, you'll have to retrieve the parent's name (I used `parent_name` as key, since we don't know what the exact column's name..):

```php
public function fetchAllSubcategories()
{
    $sqlQuery = $this->sql->select()->order('sub_name ASC');
    $sqlStmt = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($sqlQuery);
    $handler = $sqlStmt->execute();
    
    $row = [];
    
    foreach($handler as $tuple){
        $row[$tuple['subcategory_id']] = [
            'sub_name' => $tuple['sub_name'],
            'parent_name' => $tuple['parent_name']
        ];
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Then, in `CreateForm`:

```
$valueOptions = [];
foreach($subcategoriesTable->fetchAllSubcategories() as $subcategoryId => $subcategory){
    $valueOptions[] = [
        'value' => $subcategoryId,
        'label' => $subcategory['sub_name'],
        'attributes' => [
            'data-chained' => $subcategory['parent_name']
        ]
    ];
}
        
$this->add([
    'type' => Element\Select::class,
    'name' => 'subcategory_id',
    'options' =>[
        'label' => 'Subcategory',
        'empty_option' => 'Select...',
        'value_options' => $valueOptions,
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'custom-select',
    ],
]);
```

Re-reading your question, I saw that you need this value for another select. I suggest you to add parent's ID instead of parent's name, it would be easier to handle thing.

As exemple:

```php
public function formAction() {
    $subcagetoryForm = new Form();
    $subcagetoryForm->add([
        'type' => Select::class,
        'name' => 'subcategory_id',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Subcategory',
            'empty_option' => 'Select...',
            'value_options' => [
                [
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => 'Name 1',
                    'attributes' => [
                        'data-chained' => 'parent 1'
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 2,
                    'label' => 'Name 2',
                    'attributes' => [
                        'data-chained' => 'parent 2'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'custom-select',
        ],
    ]);
    return [
        'subcagetoryForm' => $subcagetoryForm
    ];
}
```

In the view:

```php
<?= $this->formElement($this->subcagetoryForm->get('subcategory_id')); ?>
```

*Result:*

[[image: Generated HTML]]

However, I'll suggest you to create a custom element to remove all this logic from the form. The custom element will be helpful if you'll need it inside another form. You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325100/form-custom-elements-with-factories)